# How to access twitter poll?

Tags: c#, twitter

Is there any way to access twitter poll data like Poll question, Option, Result etc. Basically I wanted to access all the data related to poll created by specific user. I have gone threw the twitter api doc but found nothing.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I think the answer is no as of now. https://twittercommunity.com/t/poll-support-for-rest-api/54775/32